# when i try to migrate using truffle i get this error : ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'

Tags: truffle

To use truffle migrate, I am running this command:

```
truffle migrate
```

However, I receive the following Error:

> ParserError: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen'.

I have tried everything and I am not able to find the correct solution yet.

Comment: The problem is not with your code but with the version of truffle you are using. 
Update your truffle version and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the truffle version to latest and try .I solved this issue by updating the version.